# How can i insert encrypted data to sqlite. i'm getting an error while inserting encrypted data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, ios5

How can i insert encrypted data to sqlite. i'm getting an error while inserting encrypted data. bcos the encrypted so many single quotes and double quotes so while am creating my sql the string is breaking. is there any other way to insert data without data lose. 
also i'm afraid to use add slashes method bsoc it may alter my actual encrypted data. Can anyone give me a suggestion.. Also please find my insert query function below

```
-(BOOL) insertItemData:(NSString *)encryptedData folderId:(NSString *)folderId
{
   bool giveBackValue = 0;

   database = [[[DBConnection alloc] init] autorelease];

  if(sqlite3_open([[database filePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    NSString *sql = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tbl_content (FolderId, Content) VALUES ('%@', '%@');", folderId, encryptedData] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@",sql);
    char *sqlError;
    if(sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], nil, nil, &sqlError) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        giveBackValue = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Query exec failed

    }
}
else
{
    //DB Open failed
}

return giveBackValue;
}
```

My select query function

```
-(void)getFirstJsonListInFolder:(NSString *)folderId listCarrier:(NSMutableArray **)listCarrier
{
    database = [[[DBConnection alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *dummyListCarrier = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    if (sqlite3_open([[database filePath] UTF8String], &db) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT Content from tbl_content WHERE FolderId = '%@'", folderId];

    sqlite3_stmt *result;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &result, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(result) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            char *contentList = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(result, 0);
            NSString *contentListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:contentList];
            [dummyListCarrier addObject:contentListString];
            [contentListString release];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        //Query exec failed
    }
}
else
{
    //DB Open failed
}
*listCarrier = dummyListCarrier;
}
```

Comment: Can u show us how u bind data to query. I can help you

Comment: @CrazyCreator:- I updated my question with the insert function which i used to insert data. please find the code.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid directly assigning values to the columns in sql statements. Instead you should use prepared statement and bind values to it.

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO tbl_content (FolderId, Content) VALUES ('?', '?');";
char *sql = (char *) [sql UTF8String];
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [Content UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

*This is not complete code

Comment: Still it returns `0`. Please find my updated code `NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO tbl_content (FolderId, Content) VALUES ('?', '?');"; char *sqll = (char *) [sql UTF8String]; sqlite3_stmt *sqlResult; if(sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db, sqll, -1, &sqlResult, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlResult, 1, [folderId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(sqlResult, 2, [jsonData UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            
            giveBackValue = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //Query exec failed
            
        }`

Comment: y using UTF8String while binding, see my bindings

Comment: ys i now i get `1` which means data insert successfully. also i noticed that the inserted data is not listing the the table view.. do i need to change anything in select query.. thanks for your great help ..

Comment: Happy to help.. U can accept answer if it helped you.
Show me how you are firing select Query

Comment: :) i updated my select query with my question.. please have a look and guide me please ..

Comment: NSString *s = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17092/discussion-between-deepak-pillai-and-crazycreator)